# Does TPE (from Optuna) takes account of the number of trials?

Tags: python, hyperparameters, optuna

I am using TPE sampler from optuna to optimize hyperparameters for Deep Learning vision models.
I was wondering if optuna adapt search depending of the number of trials.

If I train for 1000 trials and stop at 500, I can see that many parameters were not tried by the algorithm.
If I reduce n_trials, does TPE explore faster (and less precisely) ?
In other terms, is interupting optuna at 500 with n_step=1000 the same as using n_trials = 500 and waiting until the end.

I only have basic understanding of how TPE works.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello Phi, let me clarify your question.

Which sense do you use the word `iteration`?
The training loop count that is corresponding to the number of mini-batches, or the number of Optuna trials that is corresponding to the number of hyperparameter sets?

Comment: I was thinking of the n_trials parameters in the optimize function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and update of the description. I understand.

Answer (score 4):

> If I reduce n_trials, does TPE explore faster (and less precisely)?

No.

> ... is interupting optuna at 500 with n_step=1000 the same as using n_trials = 500 and waiting until the end.

Yes.

This is because TPE (from Optuna) is not aware of the number of remaining (or total) trials.

Comment: @user11409592 would you be able/willing to cite source(s) for your answer please?

Comment: This is the source code of the implementation https://github.com/optuna/optuna/blob/master/optuna/samplers/_tpe/sampler.py. It does not rely on the number of trials specified by the user. One can also see from the outer trial loop that there are other stop conditions besides `n_trials`, namely running time that's specified using `timeout` https://github.com/optuna/optuna/blob/master/optuna/_optimize.py